# Can we use substitution when the function is not continuous?

Tags: calculus

[This resource](https://brilliant.org/wiki/limits-by-substitution/) I am using states that the substitution rule does not hold when the function is discontinuous.

[image]
​
So I get that we can't substitute in x = zero as the limit does not exist, but I'm gathering that you cannot use the substitution rule at all when the function is discontinuous.

Can you not use substitution to find the limits of any x value when the function has one break/discontinuity in it, including points before and after the discontinuous point? For example, if you wanted to find the value at x = 1, can you not substitute 1 into the function, as the function is discontinuous at x = zero? I'm confused about this as I thought the function was continuous every where but where x is zero.

(You can click on the picture to make it bigger, not sure how to expand it on this site!)

Comment: The cited paragraph is not entirely correct: $1/x$ is not continuous at $0$ simply because it's not defined for $x=0$, nevertheless that's a *continuous* function (on all of its domain). Substituting a value for the variable is the essence of being a function, either continuous or discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function $f$ is continuous at some point $x_0$ then $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ is indeed $f(x_0)$. This is essentially the definition of continuity! It's not necessary for $f$ to be continuous *everywhere*.

Your given example is a little misleading - the function $f(x) = 1/x$ isn't defined at $x=0$, so you can't substitute anyway.

Comment: sorry for bothering again. Does the limit always approach zero? I've ntoiced when doing proofs of things like the product rule, they always write h approaches zero, should it always be this?

Comment: There's two different ideas in play there. In general, we do not have to approach zero to take a limit. It sounds like you're doing calculus, so you should look back at the definition of the derivative to see why zero comes up so much.